# Nested RecyclerView expand/collapse function is not responding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandable, nestedrecyclerview

I have 2 RecyclerView (Vertical) one inside the other. Outer RecyclerView is having a List of Child and within this Inner, RecyclerView is having list of devices available to the specific child.
The inner RecyclerView is having a condition that it should show 2 items for the first time and these are having a button on this button click the entire list of inner RecyclerView will be visible for the particular position(child).
I have easily implemented the above scenario but facing 2 problems:

1. In Outer Recyclerview item click - only the last position item is expanding, on clicking to other position the item remain collapsed.
2. After scrolling expanded view automatically collapsed itself.

Below I am sharing my code :

1. Sending complete Child list to Outer Adapter.

   adapterHomeChildList.setList(responseChildList);  // send list to the adapter.

2.Set list function and BindViewHolder of Outer Adapter

```
public void setList(List<UserWithDeviceListResponse> mChildLists) {
    childLists = new ArrayList<>();
    childLists = mChildLists;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

onBindViewHolder(....)

```
AdapterHomeDeviceList adapterHomeDeviceList = new AdapterHomeDeviceList(context);
    adapterHomeChildListBinding.setAdapter(adapterHomeDeviceList); // set inner device list adapter

    if (childLists.get(position).getDeviceList() != null && !childLists.get(position).getDeviceList().isEmpty()) {
        if (childLists.get(position).isExpanded()) {
            adapterHomeChildListBinding.setIsSeeMore(false);  // set see more button visibility
            adapterHomeDeviceList.setList(childLists.get(position).getDeviceList());
        } else {
            if (childLists.get(position).getDeviceList().size() > 2) {
                adapterHomeChildListBinding.setIsSeeMore(true);
                filter(childLists.get(position).getDeviceList(), adapterHomeDeviceList); // show top 2 item only
            } else {
                adapterHomeDeviceList.setList(childLists.get(position).getDeviceList());
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Item click interface handle

   private void setRecyclerViewExpanding(int position) {
   for (int i = 0; i < responseChildList.size(); i++) {
   if (position == i) {
   if (responseChildList.get(i).isExpanded()) {
   responseChildList.get(i).setExpanded(false);
   } else {
   responseChildList.get(i).setExpanded(true);
   }
   } else {
   responseChildList.get(i).setExpanded(false);
   }
   }
   adapterHomeChildList.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

I have searched so many questions related to this but mostly answers are using expandable listview but I am not using an expandable view.
Please do help me.
Any help will be really grateful.

Comment: It's difficult to understand your problem without seeing the code. However, there are a bunch of libraries to handle list situation. You can check this one - https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

Comment: thanks for the help and let me edit my question , I will share my code with same.

Comment: You better use `ExpandableListView` which is provided by android. It automatically handles expanded states for you.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView

Comment: I don't think I could use expandable view as I am having multiple view tapping function within inner recycler view and every time different view will expand with different features.